# Spark sliding window is not triggering when there is no data from the data stream

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a simple spark sql with time window of 5 minutes, trigger policy of every minute:

```
val withTime = eventStreams(0).selectExpr("*", "cast(cast(parsed.time as long)/1000 as timestamp) as event_time")

val momentumDataAggQuery = withTime
  .selectExpr("parsed.symbol", "parsed.bid", "parsed.ask", "event_time")
  .withWatermark("event_time", "1 minutes")
  .groupBy(col("symbol"), window(col("event_time"), "5 minutes", "60 seconds")) // change to 60 minutes
  .agg(first("bid", true).as("first_bid"), first("ask").as("first_ask"), last("bid").as("last_bid"), last("ask").as("last_ask"))

val momentumDataQuery = momentumDataAggQuery
  .selectExpr("window.start", "window.end", "ln(((last_bid + last_ask)/2)/((first_bid +  first_ask)/2)) as momentum", "symbol")
```

When there is data from the stream, it gets triggered every minute to calculate 'momentum' but stop when there is not data point. I expect it will continue using old data to update every minute even there is not enough data point.

Consider the example in the following table

In the 1st window, there is only one data point so log return is zero.

In the 2nd window, there is only two data points so it takes log(97.5625/97.4625), where 97.5625 was received at 11:53 and 97.4625 was received at 11:52:10, within the time window 12:19 <> 12:54...it went on to calculate the log return when there was sufficient data point.

However, when there was NO more data point after 15:56:12, say, for the window 12:54 <> 12:59, i expect it would take ln(97.8625/97.6625) where the input were generated at 11:56:12 and 11:54:11 respectively. However it's not the case, the red box were never generated.

Is there something wrong with my spark sql?

[image]